# Create React App production build not listening to backend API

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, api, express

I have a backend Node API Express server and a React app in two separate folders (one for backend, one for React app). My backend runs on `localhost:8000` and on my React app I have a proxy to this target via a `setupProxy.js` file using `http-proxy-middleware`. When I run the react app locally on `localhost:3000`, it can send requests to my backend correctly.

However, when I run `yarn build` on my React app for production, it doesn't seem to work. On the React app's repo, I have installed Express to serve the static files on `localhost:9000`. When I try to make a call to the backend, it just returns the `index.html` of the build folder. I'm wondering if I am doing something wrong or if I am missing something. What I would like is:

1. When user goes on `localhost:9000`, it shows the `index.html` of the `build` folder.
2. When a user clicks a button, it should send a request to `localhost:8000`, rather than sending back the `index.html`.

Here are some files in case it is needed:

`src/setupProxy.js` (this is on the React app)

```
const proxy = require('http-proxy-middleware');

module.exports = function(app) {
    app.use(proxy('/auth/google', { target: 'http://localhost:8000/' }));
    app.use(proxy('/api/**', { target: 'http://localhost:8000/' }));
};
```

`server.js` (also on React app, to serve the build folder)

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));

app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
});

app.listen(9000, () => {
    console.log('Listening on port 9000.');
});
```

Comment: When you say *"not listening"*, do you mean when you build for production it doesn't still proxy the requests? In which case... why would it? The proxy is part of the dev server setup, **not** the `build/` output. If the backend also is serving the static files in production, you don't *need* the proxy - that's the point of proxying it in dev. And if that's *not* what you're doing, i.e. you have a separate frontend and backend (as it sounds like) using that proxy in dev doesn't actually reflect the production architecture, so you shouldn't use it.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, yes, I have a separate frontend and backend. I guess I am just trying to figure out what would be the best way to serve my frontend app and have it still successfully call requests to my backend. Would I have to copy over the `build` folder to my backend repo or is there another solution (something like NGINX)?

Comment: The best way to serve your frontend app in production is to ensure it gets everything from the backend. This guarantees you avoid two common pitfalls: getting CORS issues and running webpack-dev-server in production.

Answer (score -1):

Have you added the dependency of cors in your node API.
It is needed when we are communicating to different type of environment